# Insert formula from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to have the following code insert the formula into the changed cell. I'm not receiving any errors but the code is not populating on the worksheet. Any insight into what I'm not doing?

```
formula_p1 = _
 "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of " & [value_column_header] & ",Database!R1C14, & _
     ""Key"",& Key &)"
      Debug.Print Cell.Address
          Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cell.Formula = formula_p1
```

Thank you in advance.

Update

My current code is below I'm stuck on the concatenation in the final part. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in VBA. Also I need this to be a formula that will re evaluate on changes to the "Family" part that can be done on the worksheet. The change in "Family" is accomplished from a combo box selection.

```
formula_1 = _
          "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of " & value_column_header & """,Database!$N$1,""Key""," & Concatenate(CurrentHFMFamily, G5, Left(B12, 4)) & ")"
```

Comment: `Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cell` - which cell? use `Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cell(1,1)` or `Sheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A1")` or something else

Comment: the changed cell address is being stored and the .cell is referencing the cell changed address.

Comment: Does it update when you press `Ctrl-Alt-F9`?  Then see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: If `cell` is range object (`Dim cell as Range`) , you shouldn't use `Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cell`, use just `Cell.Formula = formula_p1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final result of what i was trying accomplish. It's not pretty but it's quick and stable.

```
    =IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",ROW()))=""," ",IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Max of & _
    "&INDIRECT((ADDRESS(11,COLUMN())))&"_ADJ",Database!R1C14,"Key",& _
    LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)&CurrentHFMFamily& & _
    (OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(5))),- & _
    (MOD(COLUMN()+1,4))))),0))
```

Thanks to everyone for your ideas they helped in pointing me in the right direction.